# The client_secret Provided does not match any associated PaymentIntent on this account

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use `flutter_stripe` for a stripe connect account, But I always get the
same error: The `client_secret` provided doesn't match the client_secret associated with the PaymentIntend.
I've completed all steps according to `flutter_stripe` but I still face this error.
Below is my code Please check this and help me.

> inde.js

```
    const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const stripe = require("stripe")("secret_key");
exports.stripePaymentIntentRequest = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let customerId;

        //Gets the customer who's email id matches the one sent by the client
        const customerList = await stripe.customers.list({
            email: req.body.email,
            limit: 1
        });

        //Checks the if the customer exists, if not creates a new customer
        if (customerList.data.length !== 0) {
            customerId = customerList.data[0].id;
        }
        else {
            const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
                email: req.body.email
            });
            customerId = customer.data.id;
        }

        //Creates a temporary secret key linked with the customer
        const ephemeralKey = await stripe.ephemeralKeys.create(
            { customer: customerId },
            { apiVersion: '2020-08-27' }
        );

        //Creates a new payment intent with amount passed in from the client
        const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: parseInt(req.body.amount),
            currency: 'usd',
            customer: customerId,

        })

        res.status(200).send({
            clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
            paymentIntent: paymentIntent,
            ephemeralKey: ephemeralKey.secret,
            customer: customerId,
            success: true,
        })

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).send({ success: false, error: error.message })
    }
});
```

> PaymentService.dart

```
    Future<void> initPaymentSheet(
    {required BuildContext context, required String email, required int amount}) async {
  try {
    // 1. create payment intent on the server
    final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(
            'Firebase api link of Functions'),
        body: {
          'email': email,
          'amount': amount.toString(),
        });
    Map<String, dynamic> paymentIntentBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
    log(paymentIntentBody.toString());


    //2. initialize the payment sheet
    await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
      paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
        paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentBody["clientSecret"],
        merchantDisplayName: 'Flutter Stripe Store Demo',
        customerId: paymentIntentBody['customer'],
        customerEphemeralKeySecret: paymentIntentBody['ephemeralKey'],

        style: ThemeMode.light,
        testEnv: true,
        merchantCountryCode: 'US',
      ),
    );

    await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(content: Text('Payment completed!')),
    );
  } catch (e) {
    if (e is StripeException) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Error from Stripe: ${e.error.localizedMessage}'),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Error the Stripe of : $e')),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

**The log error print on my console is :**

```
> [log] {paymentIntent:
> pi_3LI2acCTAUDjRNFV1Ra3dahz_secret_Fcqw73pWrE4avKRyuDVzRBitG,
> ephemeralKey:
> ek_test_YWNjdF8xSlQ3amtDVEFVRGpSTkZWLDl1OE5Vdm1jTGY4T1RpaVhHOTB3NTRVSkQ5UGl4azA_00j32OYG9n,
> customer: cus_LHG2YpQP9Cgwuy, success: true}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is from a previous Stripe evaluation stage. But it worked. Slim it down to your needs.

Remember to publish your secret key to the server, so the server can talk to Stripe.

**code.dart**

```dart
Future<bool> payWithPaymentSheet(
      ProductModel productModel, PriceModel priceModel,
      {String merchantCountryCode = 'DE'}) async {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      throw 'Implementation not availabe on Flutter-WEB!';
    }
    String uid = AuthService.instance.currentUser().uid;
    String email = AuthService.instance.currentUser().email ?? '';

    HttpsCallableResult response;
    try {
      response = await FirebaseFunctions
          .httpsCallable('createPaymentIntent')
          .call(<String, dynamic>{
        'amount': priceModel.unitAmount,
        'currency': priceModel.currency,
        'receipt_email': email,
        'metadata': {
          'product_id': productModel.id,
          'user_id': uid,
          "valid_until": productModel.getUntilDateTime().toIso8601String(),
          'product_name': productModel.name.tr,
        },
        'testEnv': kDebugMode,
      });
    } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
      log(error.code);
      log(error.details);
      log(error.message ?? '(no message)');
      Get.snackbar(
        error.code,
        error.message ?? '(no message)',
        icon: const Icon(Icons.error_outline),
      );
      return false;
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> paymentIntentBody = response.data;

    await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
      paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntentBody["clientSecret"],
      currencyCode: priceModel.currency,
      applePay: false,
      googlePay: false,
      merchantCountryCode: merchantCountryCode,
      merchantDisplayName: Strings.appName,
      testEnv: kDebugMode,
      customerId: paymentIntentBody['customer'],
      customerEphemeralKeySecret: paymentIntentBody['ephemeralKey'],
    ));

    try {
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
      return true;
    } on StripeException catch (e) {
      log(e.error.code.name);
      log(e.error.message ?? '(no message)');
      log(e.error.localizedMessage ?? '(no message)');
      Get.snackbar(e.error.code.name, e.error.message ?? '',
          icon: const Icon(Icons.error_outline));
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar('An unforseen error occured', e.toString(),
          icon: const Icon(Icons.error_outline));
    }
    return false;
  }
```

**index.ts**

```js
// SETTING SECRET KEY ON SERVER:

// cd functions
// firebase functions:config:set stripe.secret_key="sk_live_51L...Noe"
// firebase deploy --only functions

let stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.secret_key);

exports.createPaymentIntent = functions
    .https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // if (!context.auth) {
    //     return { "access": false };
    // }
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            amount: data.amount,
            currency: data.currency,
            receipt_email: decodeURIComponent(data.receipt_email),
            metadata: data.metadata,
        }, function (err, paymentIntent) {
            if (err != null) {
                functions.logger.error("Error paymentIntent: ", err);
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve({
                    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
                    paymentIntentData: paymentIntent,
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Let me help please First you say about secretKey is only used on server-side like index file and then you say about firebase return functions key but I only deploy functions through console and then add the secret_key till now am I right?

Comment: Another one is I know about the test and live keys so I can't mix both of these. Now I update the code according to your given instructions. kindly check this and inform me because I still show some log error on console and can't show even a scroll bar for open payment method on screen. 
Need help.

Comment: Now just check the code. Thanks for your response.

Comment: The log on your console shows ` success: true`, I am not sure if this is an error.

Comment: This always shows 'success: true' when the client_secret error I faced but it's not showing even the payment page or a scrolling bar? why I don't know.

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope it works for you.